Azure Data Factory not creating new tables in MySQL
I am trying to copy data from Sharepoint List to Azure Database for MySQL by using Azure Data Factory. I want that everytime I run this data pipelines, ADF must create a new table and copy data over there. Now, the problem is ADF does not let me confugure sink connection to create new tables in MySQL but instead is enforcing me to select out of the existing tables to recieve data using this data factory.


Auto create table option is not available for azure MySQL database sink connector.

This feature is supported when copying data from any source into the following sink data stores.

Azure SQL Database
Azure SQL Managed Instance
Azure Synapse Analytics
SQL Server


The workaround is to manually create the table in the pipeline itself through pre-copy script.
Write a create table script in the pre-copy script text box. This will help in creating the table before copying to MySQL database.


Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#auto-create-sink-tables
